Flutter App with :flutter_native_timezone Fails to Launch on Android, Works on Windows
I am currently facing a challenging issue with my Flutter app, specifically when integrating the :flutter_native_timezone plugin. While the app runs seamlessly as a Windows application, attempting to launch it on Android through Android Studio leads to a build failure. The error suggests a problem with configuring the :flutter_native_timezone project due to an unspecified namespace. Here is the detailed error message I receive:
pubspec.yaml:
name: wgm_companion

description: A new Flutter project.

CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.2.1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
   sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
   sdk: flutter
  synchronized: ^3.1.0+1
  table_calendar: ^3.1.0
  open_file: ^3.3.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  path_provider: ^2.1.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
  import_path_converter: ^1.0.1
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  url_launcher: ^6.2.5
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.4
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  sticky_headers: ^0.3.0+2
  pdf: ^3.10.8
  math_expressions: ^2.4.0
  search_choices: ^2.2.7
  flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
  file_picker: ^8.0.0+1
  share_plus: ^8.0.2
  csv: ^6.0.0
  theme_provider: ^0.6.0
  flutter_typeahead: ^5.2.0
  firebase_core_dart: ^1.0.1
  excel: ^4.0.2
  permission_handler: ^11.3.0
  flutter_share: ^2.0.0
  syncfusion_flutter_pdf: ^25.1.37
  image: ^4.1.7
  syncfusion_flutter_xlsio: ^25.1.37
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  universal_html: ^2.2.4
  flutter_email_sender: ^6.0.2
  provider: ^6.1.2
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.6
  http: ^1.2.1
  intl: any
  path: any
  firebase_database: any
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.3.2
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
dependency_overrides:
  win32: ^5.2.0
  intl: ^0.19.0
    
    
        buildscript {
            ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
            // Setzen Sie hier die benötigte Kotlin-Version ein. Stellen Sie sicher, dass sie mit Ihrem Flutter SDK kompatibel ist.
            repositories {
                google()
                mavenCentral()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.2'
                // Verwenden Sie hier die passende Version für Ihr Projekt.
                classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            }
        }
        
        
        Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
        Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
        
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        
        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_native_timezone'.
        > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
           > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.
        
             If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.
    
    * Try:
    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
    
    BUILD FAILED in 1s
    Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
    `
    your text`

